# How can i make a container with this kind of decoration using Flutter

Tags: flutter, colors, containers, border, badge

[Please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BpCt.png). I'm not so much concerned with the child of the container. Just the decoration. I'm trying to achieve the yellow background and the check icon that's at the top right corner. So far i've only being able to make the container and give it a border colour.

**This is my code so far for the `Container`:**

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  width: 90,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color:Colors.yelloAccent[100]),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5),
    ),
    color: color,
  ),
  child: Center(child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: textColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900))),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create this with the help of `Stack` widget.

The top right triangular shape can be created by rotating a `Container` widget & adjusting its position. This can be achieved by `Positioned` & `Transform` widget.

Finally, the checkmark icon can be placed in another `Positioned` widget on top of the triangular shape.

Here, this snippet might help you:

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        // The actual container with border
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.amber, width: 2),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:36, vertical: 24),
          child: Text(
            'Payment',
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        
        // The top right triangular shape
        Positioned(
          top: -20,
          right: -80,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: pi / 4,
            child: Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
          ),),
        ),
        
        // The Icon
        Positioned(
          top: -4,
          right: -8,
          child: Icon(Icons.done, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: This totally helped me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome, buddy. You can always upvote or accept the answer so that others can see that you found this answer helpful.